The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly on dotnet publish task in azure devops
I have a dotnet publish task in a yaml file like so:
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: dotnet restore
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: dotnet restore ./My.Project/My.Project.csproj 

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: dotnet build
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore'
          projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: dotnet publish
        condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
        inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          publishWebProjects: false
          projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'              
          arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy/$(buildName)/$(project) --no-build --self-contained true'
          zipAfterPublish: True

$(buildConfiguration) - Release
$(target) - win-x64
The .csproj file settings is:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UserSecretsId>ddf84588-6f78-4c17-b74c-034aa5eb4348</UserSecretsId>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <!--Switches off XML Warnings.-->
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

The error i get is:
/home/devops/myagent/_work/_tool/dotnet/sdk/8.0.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [/home/devops/myagent/_work/1/s/My.Project/My.Project.csproj]
/home/devops/myagent/_work/_tool/dotnet/sdk/8.0.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Could not find TargetFramework alias in lock file for net8.0 [/home/devops/myagent/_work/1/s/My.Project/My.Project.csproj]

I have tried converting the dotnet build task to a bash task instead - i get the same error as above.

I got this working finally using a custom bash script:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: 'dotnet bash build'
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo running dotnet clean
                dotnet clean
                echo running dotnet restore
                dotnet restore ./My.Connector/*.csproj -r $(target)
                echo running dotnet build
                dotnet build ./My.Connector/*.csproj -c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target) --no-restore --self-contained true

          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: 'dotnet bash publish'
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo running dotnet publish
                dotnet publish ./My.Connector/*.csproj -c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target) --self-contained true --no-build -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy/staging
                echo creating '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy/$(buildName)/$(project)'
                mkdir -p '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy/$(buildName)/$(project)'

As you can see from the OP, I initially had seperate tasks that did this and it worked well but when i tried to guide the publish step/stage to only publish what i was interested, it all starting going wrong. That was because it had the publishWebProjects: true. It was simply ignoring the build and restore that had already been done so far - and repeating it all over again.
So when i saw this inefficiency in our devops processes, i had to do something about it.
Essentially all roads lead back to the restore step and ensuring you are using the right switches and then when the build and publish steps are run with the right flags (--no-restore, --no-build) they are honoured properly. This was simply not working for me, leading back to the error i was getting. Essentially the publish step/task was behaving as though no restore has been run at all.

You can accept this answer by yourself. This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions. @IbrarMumtaz

You need to also add the same argument "-r $(target)" to the "dotnet restore" and "dotnet build" command to make the project has the same target runtime of the dependencies and build environment as that of the publish environment.
For your case, you can update the steps in your YAML pipeline like as below.
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  target: 'win-x64'
  . . .

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'
      restoreArguments: '-r $(target)'
  
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet publish'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-build -c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy/$(buildName)/$(project) --self-contained true'


EDIT:
Before the 'dotnet restore' step, try to add a UseDotNet@2 task to install the .NET Core SDK (contains runtime) with version 8.
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  target: 'win-x64'
  . . .

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: 'Build'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 8.x'
    inputs:
      version: 8.x

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'
      restoreArguments: '-r $(target)'
  
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-restore -c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet publish'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: false
      projects: '**/My.Project.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-build -c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(target) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy/$(buildName)/$(project) --self-contained true'



Thank you for commenting - i will give it  ago

@IbrarMumtaz, Go ahead to try as the suggestion.

Same error as before -
System.ArgumentException: Could not find TargetFramework alias in lock file for net8.0 [/home/devops/myagent/_work/1/s/My.Project/My.Project.csproj]

It also worth adding, i cannot replicate my issue locally, it all works well.

@IbrarMumtaz, What agent are you using to run the pipeline? Microsoft-hosted agents, or Self-hosted agents installed on your own machines? Did you try to set up a self-hosed agent on your local machine to run the pipeline to see if it can work?

@IbrarMumtaz, Try to add a UseDotNet@2 task to install the .NET Core SDK 8 before 'dotnet restore'. See EDIT in above answer.

I got something working - i will share what i got working shortly

@IbrarMumtaz, If you have a solution to resolve the issue, please share the solution as an answer here and accept it. Thanks.

I finally posted my working solution, thanks for the initial steer/help.
